# PCB designing: facing problem in connecting pushbutton

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I decided to learned PCB designing using EAGLE 7.1.0. So I first of all I go through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AXwjZoyNno) video then through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCTs0mNXY24) video.

Now I started designing a board for ATmega16 microcontroller. For this I simply connect a resistor on RESET pin, And check it on board layout, till now every thing fine. Now I decide to design a library for push button, for this I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIfX3fxSpNY) video then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z9yUyguSzA) video.

Now I connect this push button with RESET pin to complete me reset circuit. Now, when I check out Board layout, there no connection between ATmega16 and push button. Here is schematic and board layout

Schematic;

[image]

Board layout:

[image]

You can see Push-button is not connecting to the chip. Why?

Comment: I Hope you're planning on adding bypass capacitors. And not actually running the ATmega on 9V.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your PCB footprint is incorrect. Outline of the button is to be drawn in tPlace(which is light gray and means physical shape of package) and not in Top(which is red and means copper).

The ratsnest is not showing up probably because you have connectivity problems. Check the part in library editor, whether it has PCB pads assigned to symbol pins.

Comment: To ensure this is not schematic issue use the 'eye' to light up the connecting net. If symbol pins also light up, they are properly connected. And if there is correct link to footprint, the pads in schematic editor will light up too.

Answer (score 0):

In schematic, try to move your button around. If the net connected to A1 doesn't follow the button, they aren't connected to each others. This could happen if the the buttons symbol was made with different grid size or no grid size at all.

Recheck your buttons footprint and especially pad connections to symbol pins. Since the atmega and the resistor are nicely connected to each other, the problem is most likely in the buttons footprint.

Edit: 
Comparing  the pin label positions on atmega and the button, it looks like pins on the button are upside down. Edit you buttons schematic symbol and flip all pins 180 degrees around and see what happens.